# What does the exclamation mark after a SASS import mean?

Tags: sass

For example, this is in the codebase I'm working in:

`@import core/mixins/retina-sprites!`

What does this mean?

Comment: Looks like a file name (`core/mixins/retina-sprites!`).

Comment: It's not a file. `core/mixins/retina-sprites.sass` is a file though. I tried removing the explanation mark (`core/mixins/retina-sprites`) and it works too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not part of the core Sass syntax.  The only add-on I am aware of that uses that syntax is the [import-once plugin](https://github.com/Compass/compass/tree/master/import-once):

> ```
> @import "something";
> @import "something!"; // this will be imported again.
> ```

The plugin prevents files from being imported more than once, but exclamation mark overrides this allowing you to import the file again.  This plugin used to be a stand alone extension, but is now bundled with Compass by default.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, we were really confused by SASS imports a while back. This explains it, thanks!